# Signing exe-files under Linux

Tags: linux, signtool

When I try to sign an EXE file under Linux with Wine, it requires some dll - mfc42.dll. Also tried install that dll with winetricks, but I cannot get it running.

Maybe you know a better way to sign a .EXE under Linux?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signing Windows application on Linux-based distros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287960/signing-windows-application-on-linux-based-distros)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is the "OpenSSL-based signcode utility", see http://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/

I haven't tried it yet, but it sounds promising (much leaner than installing Mono anyway).