# "No signature was present in the subject" error when signing code

Tags: windows, mono, openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have run into a similar problem to the on encountered here:
[How to sign code (.EXE file) with a .SPC or .PEM file from GoDaddy (using Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696021/how-to-sign-code-exe-file-with-a-spc-or-pem-file-from-godaddy-using-ubuntu)

I have used both the MONO signcode tool (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_an_executable_with_Authenticode) and osslsigncode (http://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/files/osslsigncode/) and the executables show a digital certificate present signed with "Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority".  When I view the certificate details it says "No signature was present in the subject"  I have tried with the timestamp server and without the timestamp server and there is no difference.  I am running the code on Ubuntu Precise and testing on Windows 7.

Suggestions?

Comment: I am having the same issue. If I sign the file in windows with signtool I do not have this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696021

Comment: Same issue here. Signing with `signcode` on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing this same issue with a renewed GoDaddy cert.

I'm on Debian v8 / signing a windows EXE. It's a part of a deploy/publish step.

Using the **SPC file from last year, it worked well.** With both osslsigncode and Mono's signcode.

Now I get security warnings w/ the "No signature was present in the subject"

### To FIX

I re-submitted my original CSR, and after receiving the re-re-issued cert I was able to successfully sign using osslsigncode.

Tested with `osslsigncode verify <exe-name>`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this to work by using the `-pkcs12 <pkcs12 file>` argument instead of the `-cert <certificate file>` and `-key <key file>` arguments. The .pfx file I used was generated from the exact same .spc and .pvk files I was supplying to osslsigncode, but for whatever reason, it worked while they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "No signature was present in the subject" can be caused by a mismatch between the private key used for signing and the public key in the certificate.

Comment: How would one solve the issue in this case?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen In this case use the private key matching the certificate (maybe it wasn't replaced on the computer signing the code when the certificate was renewed) or use the certificate matching the private key (if the key was replaced, but not the certificate after its renewal).