# Signing Java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, certificate, code-signing

I made a Java desktop application using Swing (myProg.jar). I currently package my application as .app for my Mac users, and I use InnoSetup to make a setup.exe file for my Windows users. I also provide a myProg.exe wrapper to launch myProg.jar.

Now, to get rid of SmartScreen and other protections from my users computers, I think that I need to sign my application. But the more I read about it, the more confusing it seems to me.

Can anyone clarify some of the following points for me?

1) What kind of certificate do I need exactly? Is there anyway to make it free or at least cheap?

2) What do I need to sign exactly? Should I sign the myProg.jar file, the .app file? The setup.exe? The myProg.exe wrapper? All of them?

**3) Solved -** How will it work when I will update my program and replace myProg.jar by a new version of myProg.jar?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am unsure about how it is of help. Is this a suggestion to use Java Web Start ?

Comment: Its not an answer, I was suggesting it, thats why I put it as a comment

Comment: Ok. But my question is more about signing, and your answer more about deployment. I already have my deployment strategy.

Answer (score 5):

Your JDK should include tool called `jarsigner`. This tool lets you sign jar files for free.

1) The key you are using for signature need to be in java keystore (default `.keystore`) You can import keys to your keystore from `.der` format.

2) You can only sign `.jar` files

3) It will just overwrite old file with new signed one. Just like simple copy. No signature verification will be performed, unless your installer does so.

Furthermore not every signature is the same. If you are for example trying to register crypto provider, then the signature signed by Oracle will be necessary to run it on Oracle JVM. see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step6

example:

To generate key:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias key_alias -keystore mystore.keystore -keysize 2048
```

To sign jar:

```
jarsigner -keystore mystore.keystore -tsa http://tsa.safecreative.org MyJARFile.jar key_alias_from_keystore
```

To verify the signature:

```
jarsigner -verify jar-file
```

I'm not sure this will solve our problem. Overall what you need to do is the sign os executable. In this case `.exe` and `.app`

A possible solution is to sign the executable of your app wrapper(in case of windows `.exe`). To do so, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764.aspx

In you are using Unix based system I would try to run Mono's sign tool. see mono doc on "signcode" (I can not provide link, not enough rep)

This should get rid of "Unknown Publisher" message, but unless you can get OS developer to sign your certificate some message will be shown to the user.

Comment: This already tends to be clearer than anything I could find until now. Thanks. I would need a few more details, though. About jarsigner, should I just auto-generate my certificate? Like `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -keysize 2048`? About SignTool, I don't get the kind of certificate I need.

Comment: As I am using GNU/Linux, I should use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287960/signing-windows-application-on-linux-based-distros but I still don't get the kind of certificate I should be using to get rid of SmartScreen...

Comment: Yes, you can generate your certificate. {{keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -keysize 2048}} will do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I successfully signed my jar file. I have a `myApp.jar.sig` file. What am I supposed to do with it ?

Comment: @Sharcoux you need to do nothing with it. The jar file is already signed. Please this link, for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html