# Android 10.0 signing my android application as system app on WINDOWS 10

Tags: java, android, windows

I'm trying to sign my application on Windows 10 using the following command.

java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 not_sign.apk sign.apk

And it gives me the following error, please help me !!

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLBIOInputStream.(OpenSSLBIOInputStream.java:34)
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:119)
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:220)
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:216)
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$Parser.generateItem(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:94)
> at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:272)
> at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown
> Source)
> at com.android.signapk.SignApk.readPublicKey(SignApk.java:184)
> at com.android.signapk.SignApk.main(SignApk.java:1007) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the
> given libraries: [conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_64,
> conscrypt_openjdk_jni]
> at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:160)
> at org.conscrypt.NativeCryptoJni.init(NativeCryptoJni.java:49)
> at org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.(NativeCrypto.java:53)
> ... 9 more

I found some solutions but they are all using Linux instead of Windows. Because of the limitation of my company, Windows is a must.

Comment: For signing Android APK files you should use `apksigner.jar` for Android SDK (and thus available on Windows, Linux, ...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signing Java desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569490/signing-java-desktop-application)

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html). Take some time to research.

Comment: Have the same error while trying to sign apk with system certificate `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path`